# My Matrix-to-List Will Not Print, Nor Does the Program Check if a Value Is In the List

Tags: python

I am trying to make a planner, and I am using the calendar module to accomplish this. Whenever I use the tolist function on the matrix, it will not print, nor will the program check if the dayChosen value is in the list. Help?

```
import os.path
import datetime
import calendar

#check if the file directory to save the events exists, if 
not, make it
if not os.path.exists("C:\Python27\Events"):
    os.makedirs("C:\Python27\Events")

#take in their month of choice, and see if the day they choose is a proper day.
while True:
    try:
        yearChosen = int(raw_input("What year will your event 
be in? "))
    if yearChosen not in range(2000,2100):
        print "That's not a valid year."
        continue
    monthChosen1 = str(raw_input("What month will your event be on? "))
    monthChosen = monthChosen1.lower()

    months = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]

    if monthChosen not in months:
        print "That's not a valid month. Check your spelling."
        continue

    if monthChosen == "january":
        month = 1
    if monthChosen == "february":
        month = 2
    if monthChosen == "march":
        month = 3
    if monthChosen == "april":
        month = 4
    if monthChosen == "may":
        month = 5
    if monthChosen == "june":
        month = 6
    if monthChosen == "july":
        month = 7
    if monthChosen == "august":
        month = 8
    if monthChosen == "september":
        month = 9
    if monthChosen == "october":
        month = 10
    if monthChosen == "november":
        month = 11
    if monthChosen == "december":
        month = 12

    #get the day and check if it's a valid day in the month
    while True:
        try:
            dayChosen = int(raw_input("What day in " + monthChosen1 + " do you want your event in? "))
            daysInMonth = calendar.monthcalendar(yearChosen, month)
            daysInMonth = daysInMonth.tolist()
            #nothing prints out here.
            print daysInMonth
            if dayChosen not in daysInMonth:
                print "That day is not valid, please input another day."
                continue
            break
        except:
            break
    break
except:
    print "Oops! Something went wrong. Please restart the program."
    break
```

I know for sure that the problem lies in the second while True loop, but I have no idea where the error could lie within it. How could I properly turn a matrix into a list so it can be checked? Whenever I try to check the matrix without doing anything with it, it always thinks any value I put into the dayChosen variable is not in the matrix.

This is the loop that seems to be the issue in the code.

```
while True:
    try:
        dayChosen = int(raw_input("What day in " + monthChosen1 + " do you want your event in? "))
        daysInMonth = calendar.monthcalendar(yearChosen, month)
        daysInMonth = daysInMonth.tolist()
        #nothing prints out here.
        print daysInMonth
        if dayChosen not in daysInMonth:
            print "That day is not valid, please input another day."
            continue
        break
    except:
        break
```

Comment: It looks like you are asking a specific question about part of this code. Please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The first thing I would modify is the try/except in the loop because it can cause silent errors. Either remove it or do `except Exception as e` then `print e`.

Comment: You could also change the twelve ifs into: `for i, month in enumerate(months): if monthChosen == month: month = i    break`

Answer (score 2):

As @Guimoute is saying the `try` is hiding an error in `.tolist()`:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

you can replace that line with a list comprehension:

```
daysInMonth = [day for item in daysInMonth for day in item]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes because `daysInMonth` is already a `list`. 
The line `daysInMonth = daysInMonth.tolist()` raises an error leading it to skip the print statement and go directly to the except. By removing this line, this specific problem will be solved.

As Guimoute pointed out, when debugging it can often be helpful to in fact remove try-excepts, or at least catch the exception and print it.